# Installing PHP FileInfo Extension on Azure

Tags: php, azure, fileinfo

Over the past two days, I have been scouring the web to figure out a way to enable the `fileinfo` extension for PHP 5.5 on Azure. I am in need of this feature in order to be able to check the type of files uploaded through a form. In my research, I have run into the following information:

First, I have found that, with PHP 5.5 (which I have running on my Azure instance), `fileinfo` should be enabled by default. That is the first concerning thing - as it is not.

Second, I have run into this [resource](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/). I followed the directions and created an App Settings variable entitled `PHP_EXTENSIONS` with a value of `bin\php_fileinfo.dll`. To see the structure of the website, visit the production repo [here](https://github.com/mattkgross/WorkoutLogger). This did not work.

In addition, I also found in the comments of the above forum that it may work if `PHP_EXTENSIONS` were changed to `PHP_Extensions`. I tried this, and still no luck. I also attempted using a backslash rather than a forward slash (as suggested in [this forum](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/09/17/using-custom-php-extensions-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx)) for the path to the dll, but that, too, was unhelpful.

Finally, in the event that the extension was present in Azure, but just not activated via `php.ini`, I used [this forum](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/07/10/configuring-php-in-windows-azure-websites-with-user-ini-files.aspx) to create a `.user.ini` to add the following line to `php.ini` that I assumed was likely commented out on the server:

`extension=php_fileinfo.dll`

Surprise! This, too, was unsuccessful.

I'm hoping there's someone out there who's had a similar problem with enabling PHP extensions in Azure that may be able to shed some light on this bleak situation. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using the wrong php_fileinfo.dll. I had to download the exact same version of PHP that was running on Azure, grab the .dll, upload it and it worked.

Comment: Do you have a link/steps as to how to download the exact Azure dll?

Comment: Run phpinfo() in Azure (create a php file that echoes phpinfo() and look for the compiler data (MSVC11), the php version (5.5.14), the architecture (x86) and always NTS.